# Regular expressions and characters

Tags: regex

Some characters, such as question marks and plus signs, have special meanings in regular expressions and must be preceded by a backslash if they are meant to represent the character itself.
May I know which is the complete list of characters which must be preceded by a backslash ?

Is it correct to say that all non alphanumeric characters must be escaped ?
And how to add a backslash to a php string , addslash() only add a slash in this few cases

- single quote (')
- double quote (")
- backslash ()
- NUL (the NUL byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it, depends. There are many flavors of regular expressions, most common:

- [BRE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)
- [ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)
- [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html) (even it have multiple flavors through programming languages)

If you want to, you should escape meta-characters described in references above with `\` , thats all.
Or surround them in `[]`, but this is kind of overkill.

Also, you can [embed](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) any UTF-8 character in PCRE (and some other flavors) via `\x{FFFF}` syntax, where
`FFFF` - byte, representing codepoint

Comment: Talking about PHP language which is the regex flavor used  ?

Comment: @gr68 they are PCRE compatible, as i remember. Also there exists page, describing php regex meta-characters https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php